Small corpus, want to find associations. Word2Vec?
I'm a psychologist, and I'm diving into the field of AI. I could really use some help for a project. This semester, I discovered Word2Vec and was mesmerized by its capability to find associations. So, I decided to try it on an artificial corpus of psychotherapy documents created by ChatGPT. However, I have a practical issue regarding the size of the vocabulary. Psychotherapy reports from an analyst don't exceed 10,000 words, and I know that cleaning this corpus typically reduces it by at least half.
I would appreciate advice on software that can maximize results with minimal data. My Word2Vec models have shown inconsistent outcomes. Specifically, when I retrain my program, it produces very different results..
I've been using Word2Vec on a full corpus of around 11,000 words. After preprocessing, it drops to 5,000 words. I've also been using PCA, which is where I became unsure about my results because the model was constantly changing.

A final vocabulary of just 5000 unique words is far smaller than what usually works well for word2vec. Are you saying that individual reports are under 10k words each (which would not at all be a problem if you had many varied reports), or that you've got only ~10k-11k words total (which would be a problem for word2vec deducing anything about the words used)? What sort of preprocessing is eliminating so many words – I'd expect either real psychotherapy reports, or even ones simulated by a qualty LLM like ChatGPT, to use a wider than 5000-word vocabulary.

That you're using synthetic texts from a generic LLM (ChatGPT) introduces all sort of other caveats as to whether you're measuring associations in anything other than ChatGPT's models. (And if that's the case: you could just be asking OpenAI's APIs for embeddings of words / phrases / texts, rather than training your own model.) OTOH, if it's synthetic data, it shouldn't be hard to get arbitrarily more, as long as you've got a good way to generate whatever varied prompts seed the whole process.

Hey, thanks for commenting. What I'm saying is that I have a total of 10K to 11K words. I'm trying to simulate a real corpus of psychotherapy sessions restricted to one patient. Keep in mind that people seeking help are usually in the early stages of their development. So I'm trying my best to extract connections in the best way possible, with a very restricted amount of data. I'm currently using lemmatization and removing the more frequent words in the corpus that are not relevant (stop words, indirect speech notation: spoke, said, mentioned).

Even in an artificial corpus, the reports get repetitive, and I helped to guarantee that since real-world reports are less beautiful than ChatGPT's. I think that's why the process created that much difference between its initial form and final. I wonder if there are any softwares that would do that type of task better. I'm also using PCA after the training phase with svd_solver='full'.

11k total words is far from the millions of words or more that will usually be used to train a word2vec model. The algorithm only learns interesting things about words from seeing the same word in many subtly-varying natural contexts – and a typical min_count parameter (below which typical implementations simply ignore words as too rare to model) is 5. So a 10k word corpus couldn't possibly yield a surviving vocabulary any larger than 2k words, unless you use an unwise & unlikely-to-be-productive lower min_count.

Lemmatization isn't often used in word2vec training – when you have enough text, it can learn subtly-different vectors for each variant form of a qword just fine. It's not clear to me from what you've said what extra value would be provided by a later PCA step on the set of word vectors - if you want a lower-dimensional representation, just train the word2vec model to learn word-vectors of fewer dimensions.

WIth insufficient data, typical word2vec dimensionalities of 100-400 will be especially doomed – how could you possibly learn such giant spaces of shades-of-meaning from few examples? You can sometimes get word-vectors on smaller datasets to at least show some of the desired word-vector relationships by using a far-smaller-dimensional model – but then you're far from the usual reasons people like dense word-vectors.

Ultimately, if you want word-vectors to be meaningful, they need to be trained on lots more text. Even for words with regard to one simulated "patient" to convey distinctions, the model would want to have seen words' uses across all contexts where they have contrasting effect. So even idea of making a model on "one case" is sketchy.

And I'd again suggest: if OK being fully-downstream of only whatever ChatGPT can understand & generate, you might as well directly use OpenAI word/text embeddings for your other analysis. It's not clear why bootstrapping your own (almost necessarily weaker) vectors from some tiny prompted subset of its potential outputs would offer any extra exploratory power.
